# C# ignore in case of Unhandled exception

Tags: c#, admin

```
    public void countdown()
    {
        label1.Text = "0";
        label2.Text = "4";
        label3.Text = "59";
        h = Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text);
        m = Convert.ToInt32(label2.Text);
        s = Convert.ToInt32(label3.Text);
        label1.Text = "0";
        label2.Text = "4";
        label3.Text = "59";

        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string hh = Convert.ToString(h);
        string mm = Convert.ToString(m);
        string ss = Convert.ToString(s);

        label1.Text = hh;
        label2.Text = mm;
        label3.Text = ss;

        s = s - 1;

        if (s == -1)
        {
            m = m - 1;
            s = 59;
        }
        if (m == -1)
        {
            h = h - 1;
            m = 59;
        }
        if (h == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Times up! You lost");
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            string path2 = "\\Puzzle";
            string fullpath = path + path2;
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fullpath);

                foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
                {
                    file.Delete();
                }
                foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
                {
                    dir.Delete(true);
                }
        }
    }
```

So Im making a mini-game(here is only the countdown timer) where you choose files then they go to a folder called Puzzle in your desktop and you have 5 minutes to finish a random puzzle and if you don´t, it will delete all files inside the folder. This might seem so stupid but I do a lot of this games with my best friends. Anyways, my question is: I noticed that, if It attempts do delete one of the files and it fails because that file is opened, it gives an Unhandled exception and doesn´t delete the rest of the files.
Is there anyway I can make it ignore that unhandled exception and just continue to delete the other files ignoring that one?
SOrry for so many text.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in a try-catch:

```
try {
   // Put delete logic here
}
catch {
  // Do nothing
}
```

This works, but a better practice is to catch a specific exception type. Since various types of exceptions could be thrown, it is a good idea to only ignore the specific exception you are anticipating. For instance, if a file is in use when C# is attempting to delete it, an `IOException` is thrown.

```
catch (IOException ex) {
   // Do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code used to delete a file in a try-catch block, and do nothing in the catch.

```
try
{
   file.Delete();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
   // do nothing
}
```

Do this try-catch block for the directories as well.